# Why is there a pink line in the chat textbox?

Tags: support, bug, chat

Sometimes I notice this:

[image: chat textbox with a pink line]

There is a pink line, in the top of the textbox. I don't remember if always in same position, I think it's always on top, but horizontal position changes.

It *might* be the mouse cursor, but that make it pink and thick? If something on SE side, would like to know why, or have it fixed.

Sadly, never found a way to reproduce it. This just happens sometimes, about once every couple of months on average.

Browser: Chrome latest stable version (currently 112.0.5615.49), OS Windows 10 Pro 21H2.

No userscripts installed, and since I'm rarely using other browsers, could never reproduce on other browsers.

Comment: Given that it's not, currently, reproducible, and you've provided minimal information, it's going to be nearly impossible to fix this, even if it's not just some rendering issue in your OS/browser and not caused by SE's code. If you can open up the browser console and try inspecting for the element associated with this, and report what you find, it would go a long way towards making it easier (possible) to fix.

Comment: @Makyen added now, good idea about inspect element, think I did it once and didn't see anything unusual, will try again when it next happens. Thanks! :)

Comment: Nothing to be worried about ... *Just stare at the pink line ... keep starring ... you feel sleepy ... close your eyes ... when you open your eyes again you follow my commands .... in 3 ... 2.... 1....*

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this kind of thing on other sites over the past few years- GitHub in particular (often with the artifact being yellow in colour).

It's probably a browser-related rendering bug. My memory is a bit foggy, but I think at one point when I got it, I tried to see if it was an element in the DOM, and it wasn't (or maybe it disappeared when I opened my devtools- again- my memory is foggy).

I use the Chrome browser on Ubuntu, Windows, and macOS. I've seen it on Windows and Ubuntu, but not macOS because I just don't use my Mac much for web browsing.

Comment: So weird, but glad to know I'm not insane. For me it's always pink, and disappear only when clicking anywhere in the screen, or of course reloading.